# Is there a good way to count the number of integers and non-integers in python?

Tags: python, integer, decimal

I am currently trying to come up with some code in python where you enter a sentence as a string & it tells you how many are integers and how many are not.

For example, if I were to input the sentence "In 2014 we Celebrated 3.14 with 3 whole pies" I would need two separate outputs to give me that there were 2 integers and one non-integer

I'm frankly stuck after counting how many numbers are in an input

```
def integer_count(entry):
  num_integers = len(re.findall((r'\d+'), entry))
  return(num_integers)
```

I figured if I could find out how many times a number isn't an integer, I could just use that to give me that number & subtract it from the rest, but I cannot find that either.

I have tried multiple times counting how many numbers, I have been using regex, but cannot find a way to make it work with anything else

I know how to do this in theory, but I'm completely clueless on how to do it in practice and every time I search for my answer it nearly always gives me results on how to find a number's decimal place rather than what i'm looking for

Comment: I would suggest starting by splitting on whitespace, `entries = entry.split()`, then looping over entries and checking each one for being an integer. Probably easier than a regex.

Comment: If you are counting `3.14` as a "non-integer", you should probably count "we", "celebrated", etc as non-integers as well. `3.14` is not a number here; it's a date format.

Answer (score 1):

If you know everything is going to be whitespace separated then I would use `split` to separate it into tokens and check for a `.` character. If it has a `.` try to cast it to a float - if that works its a real number, otherwise it could be a word with a fullstop `fin.`

```
def integer_count(entry):
    entry_split = entry.split(' ')
    int_count = 0
    decimal_count = 0
    for word in entry_split:
        if '.' in word:
            try:
                float(word)
                decimal_count +=1
             except:
                pass
        elif word.isnumeric():
            int_count +=1
    return (int_count, decimal_count)
print(integer_count("hello world 1 2 2.3"))
```

if that doesn't work for you I'd do a regexp looking for

```
int_count = len(re.findall((r'\d+'), word))
decimal_count = len(re.findall((r'\d+.d+'), word))
return int_count-decimal_count`
```

as as long as someone hasn't put in `hello 2.3.3` will probably work too.

Comment: Fingers crossed, no one puts a space before the dot . 

Comment: Its not a trivial problem really. For example is ` .2` a fullstop and then a 2? or is it 0.2?What do you want to do with `0.  4` or `0  . 4`? or `2-3.2` etc.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be beautiful, but this works for me. Check out this thread for some more elegant ways to discern numbers/ints/floats: [How do I check if a string represents a number (float or int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-represents-a-number-float-or-int)

```
def is_float(s):
try:
    float(s)
    try:
        int(s)
        return False
    except ValueError:
        return True
except ValueError:
    return False

string = "In 2014 we Celebrated 3.14 with 3 whole pies"
words = string.split()

ints = [int(w) for w in words if w.isnumeric()]
print(ints)
print(len(ints))

floats =[float(w) for w in words if is_float(w)]
print(floats)
print(len(floats))
```